# Forcing a browser to use a particular network adapter by using a local proxy server (Windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy

I have two internet connections on my PC. A fast metered connection and a slow connection without a download cap. My intention is to use the fast connection in Firefox for browsing, Youtube etc. while using the slow connection for everything else (download manager, Dropbox, downloading game updates on steam etc.). Basically, anything that doesn't require fast, low-latency connections should use the slow network.

Using the connection metric, I gave greater priority to the slow connection so everything would use that. Then I tried to use ForceBindIP software to force firefox to use the fast connection and have gotten mixed results. It will sometimes stop working for no apparent reason and nothing short of disabling the slow network will work (which then makes EVERYTHING use up my limited data cap on the fast network).

While playing with virtual machines, I noticed that Vmware has the option to bind the guest to a specific network adapter on the host. So this is one roundabout way to make the firefox inside my VM only use the fast connection (it will literally not even know that there are other network connections available).

This is obviously a much better solution than ForceBindIP and I want to bring this function to my host system without the need of a virtual machine. Which brings me to the task at hand:

1. I want to run a proxy server on my computer that can bind to the fast network adapter (the way VMWare can do).
2. I will tell Firefox to connect to the internet using this locally hosted proxy server. The only way out for Firefox will be via the proxy server and thus the fast connection.
3. That proxy server should not allow any computer on the internet to connect to it and gain access to my system. It should only allow outgoing connections.

   - Is this task possible?
   - Will it yield the results I want or am I overlooking something important?
   - And finally, I would appreciate software recommendation for the proxy server to use and a brief guide on how to configure it to block external connections.

My operating system is Win 7 64bit.

Comment: I don't have Windows 7 available to check but is "Turn on Remote Desktop IP Virtualization" available on the platform:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise-mobility-security/configuring-remote-desktop-ip-virtualization-ii/ba-p/246850

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find that option in gpedit.msc. It goes all the way to "Remote Desktop Session Host" but there is no subfolder called "Application Compatibility".

I have a suspicion that this method works similar to ForceBindIP and will have similar problems e.g. when browser launches a new process for some purpose which will not be bound to the specified network interface.

Comment: Thanks. I know you can use that option at least on terminal servers to have processes use their own ‘virtual’ IP which might have been helpful.